# Tokenize command line input in C

Tags: c, solaris, strtok

trying to take a line of text and tokenize it into a filename and arguments for `execvp()`. Here's my code, `getArguments()` is the broken function. Currently, trying to print `arguments[0]` results in a bus error.

```
char* getFilename(char* input) {
    return strtok(input, " &");
}

char** getArguments(char* input) {
    char** arguments;
    int k = 0;
    char* tokenized;
    tokenized = strtok(input, " &");
    tokenized = strtok(NULL, " &");
    while (tokenized != NULL) {
        arguments[k] = tokenized;
        ++k;
        tokenized = strtok(NULL, " &");
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

I am using it in the following manner later in my code:

```
char* filename = getFilename(line);
char** arguments = getArguments(line);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to getFilename modifies the string by placing a '\0' character after the first token. Then you attempt to restart at the beginning in getArguments. That only yields the first token since the string is now prematurely terminated. You can fix this problem by getting rid of getFilename and getting it from getArguments.

```
char **arguments = getArguments(line);
char *filename = arguments[0];
```

Also, you must allocate space for each pointer in the `char **arguments;` array. You can use [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) to grow the array dynamically. However, there are more efficient approaches.

```
char** getArguments(char* input) {
    char** arguments;
    int k = 0;
    char* tokenized;
    arguments = calloc(1, sizeof (char *));
    tokenized = strtok(input, " &");
    /* don't eat the first token here since we want the filename in arguments */
    while (tokenized != NULL) {
        arguments[k] = tokenized;
        ++k;
        arguments = realloc(arguments, sizeof (char *) * (k + 1));            
        tokenized = strtok(NULL, " &");
    }

    /* an extra NULL is required to terminate the array for execvp() */
    arguments[k] = NULL;

    return arguments;
}
```

Comment: I think I can fix the second problem, but what about the first? :(

Comment: Wait, do you not want to filename in arguments? If so, then just removed the `tokenized = strtok(input, " &");` line.

Comment: Let me add that it is customary to pass the program name as the first argument. So, there is no need to remove the filename from the argument list.

Comment: If you say that it is customary to pass the program name as the first argument, then I'll trust you! I thought you were not supposed to do that, but then again, I am new to C. :)

Comment: OK, then what I have is the way to go. In fact, you don't really need a pointer to the filename, just do `execvp(*arguments, arguments);`.

Comment: Also, don't forget to `free(arguments);` when you are done with the memory!

Comment: One more question, if the user types a blank line, will `*arguments == NULL`?

Comment: Yes, `arguments` would contain a single pointer to NULL allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory for `char **arguments` - it's just a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`char **arguments` is a single pointer.  Consider where it points....

Hint:  it should point somewhere useful where it can hold multiple pointers.